# Which tool is good to collect tweets on 50 keywords over the last 5 years and then analyze them with the LDA algorithm or sentiment analysis?

Tags: data-mining, sentiment-analysis, topic-model, lda, twitter

I want to find tweets from the last 5 years to a topic. For this I decide for 50 Keywords (related to the main topic), where I want to find data on Twitter. I want to find out how the trend on the subject is, are there any opposing/negative opinions, are there recognizable patterns, ... (I am also unsure which possibilities I have to get something useful from the data)

I totally new to Data Science and never done it before.
I have found the following tool https://algorithmia.com/pricing and https://monkeylearn.com/ . Especially Algorithmia looks like it could help me. Are there other alternatives that could help me with this task? Since my programming skills are not very good and my data science skills are not existing, I thought it would be the easiest thing to buy a tool.

I am happy about any advice. :)

Comment: @https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/104675/loretta Did you find the R & RStudio info helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for Algorithmia and monkeylearn, I don't know if you will find much help for those here due the fact that [Python](https://www.anaconda.com/) and [R](https://cran.r-project.org/)/[RStudio](https://rstudio.com/) are the predominant 'data science' open source (read: free) platforms. Otherwise, if Algorithmia or monkeylearn has tutorials go for it.

The project you are interested in doing is not trivial (with no experience) but completely within the grasp of a novice given enough time. May I suggest starting with [R](https://cran.r-project.org/)/[RStudio](https://rstudio.com/). This is simply my opinion based on my learning path. "Your mileage may vary!" Then find some tutorials such as [Towards Data Science](https://towardsdatascience.com/twitter-sentiment-analysis-and-visualization-using-r-22e1f70f6967) and see how it goes.